# SQL Server 2008 - pivoting data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help pivoting some data

```
SELECT 
   [contact_list_name] as 'Table'
   ,[ov_number_dialed] as 'Number Dialed'
   ,convert(date, [time_of_contact], 101) as 'Date'
   ,convert(time, dateadd(hour, -7,[time_of_contact]), 108) as 'Time'
   ,agent_full_name as 'Agent'
   ,[response_status] as 'Disp'
FROM 
   [meldb].[dbo].[cl_contact_event]
```

which gives me results like this:

[image]

I want to pivot out or show the results so that the disp is in a line like

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a maximum number of `disp` records?  If so, you can use `pivot` or `max` with `case`.  If not, you'll need to use `dynamic sql`.  There are tons of SO posts about it.

Comment: Ill go with a max of 6 disp records, dont think i need more than that. 

I just cant get pivot to work righ or at all...

Comment: Do you know what those 6 values are -- always `DAM`, `CBS`, etc?  If those are dynamic, then you're forced to use `dynamic sql`.

Comment: DAM, DNA, NML, NN, NR, NAN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comments, an easy way to pivot is to use `max` with `case`:

```
select 
    [contact_list_name] as 'Table'
    , [ov_number_dialed] as 'Number Dialed'
    , convert(date, [time_of_contact], 101) as 'Date'
    , convert(time, dateadd(hour, -7,[time_of_contact]), 108) as 'Time'
    , agent_full_name as 'Agent'
    , max(case when [response_status] = 'DAM' then response_status end) as 'Disp1_DAM'
    , max(case when [response_status] = 'DNA' then response_status end) as 'Disp2_DNA'
    ...
FROM [meldb].[dbo].[cl_contact_event]
GROUP BY
    [contact_list_name] 
    , [ov_number_dialed] 
    , convert(date, [time_of_contact], 101) 
    , convert(time, dateadd(hour, -7,[time_of_contact]), 108) 
    , agent_full_name
```

Comment: how would i account for disps changing orders based on when they are used?

i appreciate your help